# Why is eye accommodation necessary?

Tags: optics, lenses, vision

Why is eye accommodation necessary when infinite number of light rays  come from a specific point of an object and we can use any pair of rays we need and the curvature of the lens need not to be changed?[image: here's the pic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your eyeball is a screen. It will record (send a message to the brain about) each and every beam (or ray) of light that hits it.

Ideally the situation described by you is identical to that when we do not require a lens. If we do add a lens, all it does is just provides a larger field of view, but we can still go about without it.

Now imagine a situation where the rays were coming randomly from every place and hitting every other part of your retina. All you would see just blurred white light. (This is actually a medical condition. See Aphakia) Similar to what happens if you try to use a projector in a very brightly lit room or outdoors on a sunny day.

And now consider the dire opposite where we have a pinhole camera. Although we get a sharp image, it is very faintly lit, and our retina isn't sensitive enough to pick up all the information from this tiny amount of light. (Try making a fist with a tiny hole and look through it. The world is still visible, but very faintly lit and almost dark.

So what the accommodation of the eye actually does is it:

1. Prevents light from places other than where we want to focus to reach our eyes.
2. Makes sure that whatever light is there, its all focused to where it is supposed to be ensuring the brightest image possible.

Comment: Well actually that wasn't my claim. I was talking about eye accommodation. I asked that it wasn't necessary  to change the focal length of the eye every now and then.

Comment: When you say, fix a lens on the eye, isn't one of the most basic case a lack of a lens itself? What if the lens I fixed was just a thin membrane?

Maybe calling it your claim is wrong, and I will edit it as so.